# updating data for handlebars without regenerating the whole template

Tags: javascript, templates, data-binding, handlebars.js

I would like to use handlebars as my templating engine either with my own custom code or with something like ember/backbone.  My concern is that when I update the data that was used to seed the template (like add an extra row to an array in the data structure), then its going to have to re-render the entire template and replace the previous html with it correct?

Perhaps I don't know enough about this subject, but is there a way to insert, update, delete only the necessary changed portion of the templates resulting html without re-rendering the whole thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, by using an [SPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) like Backbone, Emberjs, Angular or another one out there, which is why they are for.

By simple using Handlebars or any other pure template engine you always will have to re-render the template by passing the new data and then inserting it into the DOM.

That being said, maybe there is way by using an upper layer to do all the binding between DOM and data to make then in sync, maybe [HTMLBars](https://github.com/tildeio/htmlbars) or something else, but it is still in development, tought.